# Intellij Idea does not show logs in docker

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, boot

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022, which is up to date. I have a Spring Boot application and a remote Docker. I can connect to docker through ssh (via putty, Idea ets) and it works fine.
The problem is when I deploy an application in Idea I can't see the log file. Can't see how the application starts and how the logging system works (sl4j), that is absolutely silent for me. Moreover, if I want to connect the app later and see the log in app it will not show  information for me, but if I start the app locally (without docker, only in Idea) it shows the needed data.
Can anyone help to me with this little inconvenience and give me some advice how to set up Idea, network or something else to achieve the log data?

I have googled but found no information :(

Comment: you can check that container logs via terminal `docker logs myapp`

Comment: thank you. Yes I can, but why is it impossible from Idea?

Comment: intellij also has terminal option, you can type in that attached terminal also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update IDE to the latest version.

Comment: I had to upvote this because IDE update really helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed a new version and the issue had been resolved. So easy :)

Comment: Glad that the issue has been resolved. Could you please provide more information for future readers about the issue and exactly which version resolved the issue? More details on how you came to the solution? I would also suggest that you take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: surely. 

 I have installed IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) and the issue has been resolved (I can't see docker's log in "Services"

Comment: I understand and I am happy that you have resolved the issue! Perhaps you could *in detail* explain the issue in your question and provide additional information in your answer what was wrong and why the new version fixed the issue?